# How to display the highest value from a column in a sqlite database in lua corona

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk, null

I'm creating a game and when it finishes it stores it in a database (code below that adds it)

```lua
-- open SQLite database, if it doesn't exist, create database
local path = system.pathForFile("leaderboards.sqlite", system.DocumentsDirectory)
db = sqlite3.open( path ) 
print(path)
-- setup the table if it doesn't exist
local tablesetup = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS leaderboards (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, score INDEXED);"
db:exec( tablesetup )
print(tablesetup)
-- save student data to database
local tablefill = "INSERT INTO leaderboards VALUES (NULL,'" .. score .. "');"
print(tablefill)
db:exec( tablefill )
--   close database
db:close()
print("db closed")
```

Then I want at the top of the screen to display the highest score so this is my display function

```lua
local function highScore()
    -- open database    
    local path = system.pathForFile("leaderboards.sqlite", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    db = sqlite3.open( path ) 
    print(path)
    --print all the table contents
    local sql = "SELECT MAX(score) FROM leaderboards"
    local val = db:exec(sql)
    local t = display.newText("Best: "..val, 300, -20, nil, 28)
    print(val)
    t:setTextColor(255,255,255)
    db:close()
end
```

Right now on the screen it is just saying 0 and not the high score or any screen. The values are being entered in the database but my sql statement isn't displaying it.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is

```
local val
for x in db:urows "SELECT MAX(score) FROM leaderboards" do val = x end
```

Or

```
local sql = "SELECT MAX(score) FROM leaderboards"
for val in db:urows(sql)
  local t = display.newText("Best: "..val, 300, -20, nil, 28)
  print(val)
  t:setTextColor(255,255,255)
end
```

See the `urows` documentation [here](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki#db_urows).

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki#db_exec):

> db:exec
>           db:exec(sql[,func[,udata]])
>           db:execute(sql[,func[,udata]])
>
> Compiles and executes the SQL statement(s) given in string sql. The
>   statements are simply executed one after the other and not stored. The
>   function returns sqlite3.OK on success or else a numerical error code
>   (see Numerical error and result codes).
>
> If one or more of the SQL statements are queries, then the callback
>   function specified in func is invoked once for each row of the query
>   result (if func is nil, no callback is invoked). The callback receives
>   four arguments: udata (the third parameter of the db:exec() call), the
>   number of columns in the row, a table with the column values and
>   another table with the column names. The callback function should
>   return 0. If the callback returns a non-zero value then the query is
>   aborted, all subsequent SQL statements are skipped and db:exec()
>   returns sqlite3.ABORT.

In your code, the `local val` receives sqlite3.OK, which probably equals `0`. You need to provide a callback function to receive row data, for example

```lua
local function maxscorecb(udata, ncols, colvals, colnames)
  --Assuming that it's always one row and value
  udata[1] = colvals[1]
  return 0
end

--print all the table contents
local sql = "SELECT MAX(score) FROM leaderboards"
local scoretab = {}
local val = db:exec(sql, maxscorecb, scoretab)
local t = display.newText("Best: "..scoretab[1], 300, -20, nil, 28)
print(val)
t:setTextColor(255,255,255)

db:close()
```

P.S. Haven't tested it, just based on reading the docs.